# PowerShell DbaTools Pass Hashtable to Invoke-DbaQuery

Tags: powershell, hashtable, dbatools

I am trying to pass a Hashtable called `$SqlInstanceParams` to the Invoke-DbaQuery dbatools command:

```
Invoke-DbaQuery -SqlInstance "X" -Database "X" -Query "Set-SQLInstance" -SqlParameters $SqlInstanceParams -CommandType StoredProcedure
```

Displaying the hashtable variable I have populated, all looks fine but when the query executes I got this error:

> ```
> No mapping exists from object type System.Version to a known managed
> provider native type.
> ```

Do I need to somehow convert this hashtable or list each parameter out individually like so instead of just passing the hashtable variable:

```
$SqlInstanceParams = @{IsClustered = $SqlInstanceParams["IsClustered"]; 
                      ServerName = $SqlInstanceParams["ServerName"] etc}
```

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be a data mapping issue between the Hashtable values and the SQL table.